# Why didn't I need to use else if statement in first block of code?

Tags: javascript, if-statement

Here is the first block of code.

```
function assignment1() {
var number = prompt("Enter a number");
if (number>=1 && number<=10) {
    alert("The number is between 1 and 10.")
        }
if (number>=11 && number<=20) {
    alert("The number is between 11 and 20.")
        }
}
assignment1();
```

Here is the second.

```
function assignment2() {
var number = prompt("Enter a number");
if (number<50 || number>200) {
    alert("valid number!")
        }
else if (number>=50 || number<=200) {
    alert("good number!")
        }
}
assignment2();
```

Both blocks of code are working fine, however I'm just wondering why I had to use a else if statement for the 2nd and not the 1st.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the if conditions in your first block are mutually exclusive and the ones in your second block aren't.

In your first block, any given number cannot be `<= 10` and `>= 11` at the same time. But in your second block a number like e.g. `300` would certainly be `> 200` and `>= 50`, thus matching both conditions.

Answer (score 1):

TLDR: Using `if` and using `if-else` would do exactly the same since the conditions are mutually exclusive.

Consider:

```
var condition1 = number>=1 && number<=10
var condition2 = number>=11 && number<=20
```

Then

```
if (condition1) {
   // case 1
} else if (condition2) {
   // case 2
}
```

is the same as writing:

```
if (condition1) {
   // case 1
}

if (!condition1 && condition2) {
   // case 2
}
```

Since `condition1` and `condition2` are mutually exclusive, if `condition2` is `true`, then `!condition1` is also true, therefore the above is equivalent to:

```
if (condition1) {
   // case 1
}

if (condition2) {
   // case 2
}
```

However, most programmers would still use `if else`.

In the second example the conditions are:

```
var condition1 = (number<50 || number>200)
var condition2 = (number>=50 || number<=200)
```

The conditions are not mutually exclusive because they can `true` for the same number e.g. for number `0`. The second condition is actually `true` for every number therefore the code could also be written as:

```
if (condition1) {
   // case 1
} else {
  // case 2
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Writing like the 2nd statement is logic and response to the syntax of condition in programming. The 1st work find in this context, but it might not work well in some other context of condition.